etymology of 成立 and 成り立つ
成立 (せいりつ) and 成り立つ share the same kanji as well as at least one sense. Sense 1 of 成り立つ is defined here as:

ある物事ができ上がる。すっかりある状態になる。成立する。

成立 is also attested in Chinese (see here). I can't find specific information about its etymology, so I assume it's a 漢語 that was first created in China and then imported in Japan.
I find it hard to believe that 成り立つ was independently coined in Japan, and that by sheer coincidence it shares the same kanji and (at least partially) the same meaning as 成立.
So how did 成り立つ come about? Was this 大和言葉-looking compound verb created as a calque to 成立 on the basis of the already-established correspondences 成 = 成る and 立 = 立つ?
Or perhaps, 成り立つ was independently coined in Japan carrying a different meaning (sense 1 quoted below), and later further senses were added by analogy with Chinese-origin 成立?

① 一人前になって世に立つ。人となる。成長する。立身する。
[初出の実例]「おのづから、宿世宿世に人となりたちぬれば」(出典：源氏物語（1001‐14頃）乙女)

I feel like this is not an isolated case, either. If you have info about this general phenomenon, please share it as well.

I'm not sure if 成立 is a case of this, but consider that Japanese-derived compounds like 取消 have been re-imported into Chinese. One way to resolve this question would be to see what the earliest attestations of 成立 are in Chinese, and whether it makes sense to consider a Japanese origin.

According to Wiktionary, Japanese 成立 (せいりつ) descends from the Chinese term: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%88%90%E7%AB%8B#Descendants

The 成立 entry from the NKD at Kotobank lists a first attestation of 716 in part of the 続日本紀 (Shoku Nihongi). This strongly implies that this compound was already extant in Middle Chinese at that time.

Meanwhile, 成り立つ isn't attested until 源氏物語 (The Tale of Genji), written over 1001-1014.
